# Page numbers in roman numerals instead of cardinal numbers

Tags: page-numbering

I don't understand why in the first chapter of this book, the page number is made of roman numerals, like in preface pages

```
\documentclass[italian,a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{forest}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{indentfirst}



\geometry{textheight=24.2cm,textwidth=16cm}
\pagestyle{headings}
\frenchspacing

\title{
\huge Guida semplificata a Herbertlandia} 
\author{Salvo Errori}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduzione}

Il gatto è sul tavolo. Il gatto mangia il cibo. Il gatto è sul tavolo. Il gatto mangia il cibo. Il gatto è sul tavolo. Il gatto mangia il cibo.


\end{document}
```

The preamble has been written having in mind the example [GAPIL book](http://gapil.truelite.it/svn/trunk/gapil.tex)

[(click here for complete PDF version)](http://gapil.gnulinux.it/files/2011/12/gapil.pdf)

Comment: The `\frontmatter` macro switches to roman numerals. The `\mainmatter` macro, if used, switches to arabic numerals (and restarts numbering at 1). Thus, insert the instruction `\mainmatter` before the first `\chapter` instruction.

Comment: @Mico thank you. You should fill an answer so I can assign you the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks. I hesitated to write this down as an answer because I suspected this question had come up before. I think Andrew Swann has identified such a posting in the meantime.